# Upgrading to jetty 9.3.1.v20150714 caused Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: jetty

The error message doesn't seem helpful. Any idea what is going wrong?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a standard error from Java indicating that you are using an older JVM than the Classes you are attempting to run. (the `Unsupported major.minor version` numbers might be different depending on scenario, but the number you are presented indicates the version of Java you need).

I usually use the [Wikipedia article on "Java Class File"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) to find out what the Class file major.minor version number translates to as far as a Java JVM requirement.

[As for Jetty 9.3+, that requires Java 8 per its announcement email.](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00080.html)

Comment: Wikipedia says that version 52.0 is Java 8

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means the JRE installed on your machine is older than the minimum required by the project / library.

I suspect Jetty 9.3.1 now requires at least JRE 1.7

What does "java -version" return in your console?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: I think that is the latest.

Comment: Apologies i missed your last comment, it is important to note Java 7 is now out of support (since April 2015). Jetty 9.3.1 was just released in May 2015 so they've chosen to make Java 8 the minimum for 9.3.1 (if for some reason you must stay on Java 7 and you dont need HTTP 2.0 / Jetty 9.3 feature xyz,  Jetty 9.2 is Java 7 compatible) - Jetty 9.3 Release notes https://webtide.com/jetty-9-3-features/