# Best way to resolve unsupported major minor version exception coming due to maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project that needs to be shipped to be running with JDK 1.7(I know it is EOL but the migration to JDK 1.8/1.9 is still a couple quarters away).

I get the exception:

> org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/HandlerCollection : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0
>   org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/HandlerCollection : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0 Server exiting.

I resolved this by following [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643512/upgrading-to-jetty-9-3-1-v20150714-caused-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0) post , which mentioned downgrading the jetty version to 9.2 which resolved the above exception. Now the next exception is coming:

> org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0
>   org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0 Server exiting.

Does this mean that I have to keep on fixing each exception that comes one-by-one by downgrading the dependency versions or is there a smarter approach to this?

If this config matters I have done the configuration [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24791708/2458858) in my eclipse to make my application Java 1.7 compliant(that may be the reason my app is not throwing unsupported exception, rather it's the dependencies which are throwing): 
And also added this in my pom.xml (but it won't matter for dependencies)

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
  </properties>
```

**EDIT:** Am using maven shade plugin to build a shaded jar of dependencies. The maven shade plugin configuration is:

```
<plugin>                                
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>                 
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>                                                                        
        </execution>                                        
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yes you have to downgrade each of the dependencies which is not compatible with JDK 7 requirement otherwise it will fail with runtime exceptions...Apart from that JDK 7 is too old furthermore you should at least go with JDK 8 of which the ends is not far away as well.. JDK 9 would the best choice...

Comment: @khmarbaise can you also suggest how to find the compatible versions. For e.g if I am trying to resolve the second exception, how do I find the atrifact version of `spring -web` compatible with JDK 1.7?

Comment: I would suggest to take a deep look into the release notes of the spring parts where you hopefully find hints...